# Running JADE on Amazon EC2 and facing IP problems

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, agent, agents-jade, multi-agent

Each Amazon EC2 instance has public and private IP address. When I am fetching AID it gives me instance's private IP while I want public IP.

```
       this.getAID()
```

It has result

```
        ( agent-identifier :name ping1@cloudPlatform  :addresses (sequence http://PRIVATEIP:7778/acc ))
```

I want to has Public IP instead of Private IP. How can I do this ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Elastic IPs** are used to communicate with outer world. The Amazon instances can create intenral network like LAN having n number of instances. They use these IP Addresses, therefore for external communication there are Elastic IP Addresses. Amazon charge very reasonable amount as well.